# Placing balls into slots with a modular restriction

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n_1, n_2, \ldots , n_c$ balls of $c$ different colors, and $n = n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_c$ slots which can take one ball each.  The slots are numbered form $1$ to $n$, and the numbers assigned to the colors are relevant.

One is tasked with placing the $n$ balls in the $n$ slots, but it is forbidden to place a ball with color $k$ into any slot with number $s \equiv k \pmod{c}$.

For example, with three colors, $21$ balls and $21$ slots, the balls of color $1$ cannot be placed into slots $1, 4, \ldots 19$.

> I'm trying to find a closed form expression (which can of course include use of rising/falling powers, but Stirling numbers and Eulerian numbers and the like are also okay)  for the number $N(n_1, n_2 \ldots n_c)$ of distinguishable ways these balls can be placed in the slots.

Balls of the same color are considered indistinguishable; each slot is distinguishable from all other slots.

Many combinations of $n_i$ lead to no solutions at all;
it is acceptable to have an expression for the number that applies to the caes where it is non-zero, and a set of rules which mechanically determine whether to apply that expression or say that $N=0$.

Without the restriction the answer would be the multinomial expression
$$
N (n_1, n_2 \ldots n_c)= \frac{n!}{n_1! n_2! \cdots n_c!}
$$

The two-color case $c=2$ is easily handled.
$$
N(n_1, n_2) = [n_1 = n_2] + [n_1 = n_2-1]
$$
where the notation [a = b] means a number which is $1$ if $a=b$ and $0$ otherwise.  But even for $c=3$ this seems like a tough problem.

Comment: Just a trivial note: it is a coefficient of $x_1^{n_1}\ldots x_c^{n_c}$ in $$\prod_{s=1}^{n}\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant c\\k\not\equiv s\pmod{c}}}x_k=\prod_{r=1}^{c}\left(\sum_{k\neq r}x_k\right)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-r}{c}\right\rfloor+1}.$$